# bootstrap drop down login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, authentication, dropdown

I'm new to asp.net mvc and I'm trying to create a website using bootstrap theme. I'm stuck at two places - 1) I'm not able to render views of pages, it gets hidden behind the layout. 2) Dropdown for a login form doesn't work for me in VS-2013 but the same code works in an online editor. Please review my code.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">


        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">


                <li class="active">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("index", "home")">
                        <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class=" active">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index","About")"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"> </i>Contact</a></li>

                    </ul>



            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" >
                <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-log-in"></i> Login</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">

                                 <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>

                                   <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">


                        <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>


                        <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>


                        <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>


                        <li class="divider"></li>


                        <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>


                    </ul>


                </li>


                @*<li class="dropdown"><a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Sign Up</a></li>*@
            </ul>






        </div>
    </nav>


<div class="container body-content">

    @RenderBody()
    <hr/>
</div>




<div id="footer" class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">

        <p class="text-capitalize">&copy; </p>

    </div>

</div>










@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: I figured that the first few lines of the home page view are hidden behind the nav bar if it's fixed at top. On removing navbar-fixed-top, I can see the heading of the home page. But I want navbar to be visible even while scrolling, can someone please tell me a way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: If you use `.navbar-fixed-top` you need to add a margin before your content (to push it below the height of the navigation).  In addition, it is not necessary to wrap your `.navbar` in a `.container-fluid`.

Comment: thanks. I used padding-top and it worked. Could you help me with the dropdown? The code doesn't seem to work. I'm not getting a drop down list

Comment: You can see great examples of Bootstrap dropdown in conjunction with its Navbar option here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar   Your formatting is all over the place in the above code... `class="active"` should not be on every item, for example, and the navigation you are showing doesn't actually HAVE a dropdown.

Comment: My bad. I included the drop down list in the above edited code. I used active to show which tab the user is currently viewing. It's more for highlighting purpose. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with the drop down menu. Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in comments to your original question, you need to adjust for the height of `.navbar.navbar-fixed-top` so that your content appears appropriately.  Regarding issues related to your dropdown not functioning properly, I'm not able to reproduce that, see a Bootply fiddle:

http://www.bootply.com/GA3c5vtK3v

It's possible that your ASP elements are interfering with any sort of fiddle example you're rendering (I've commented those out where they would interfere with the layout).  In addition, please note that the default dropdown behavior is on a click event, not on hover.

When you click on your dropdown element it functions as expected.

Comment: So it works in the bootply fiddle right? I'm sorry I don't understand where I'm going wrong with the dropdown list. I have tried so many things and instead of hover I added a button for dropdown, that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: And umm where have you commented it out? I can see only the code that I have commented

Comment: ... did you open the Bootply.com link?  There are items like `@*` and `*@` that I've added `<!-- -->` to in order to ensure they aren't being rendered, since their rendering breaks your navbar in the fiddle.

Comment: yes, @* and *@ is for commenting out the code in asp.net. But I removed that part of the code and still the dropdown list doesn't work.

Comment: The only dropdown in your code is "Messages" which, when clicked, drops down a menu of Inbox, Drafts, Sent Messages, and Trash.  This works correctly in the above fiddle; was there some other dropdown you believe should have been implemented?

Comment: no no, that's the only dropdown that needs to be implemented. It works in the fiddle but it doesn't work in asp.net (using VS 2013 and asp.net mvc 4). I implemented the above code in layout.cshtml page. Everything works fine except the dropdown. It's beyond me as to why it works in the fiddle and not in asp.net

Comment: it finally worked phew! I added these two references - <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
I'm guessing that there was some issues with jqery and bootstrap, that's why the code was working in bootply and not in asp.net. And it also works as a hover just like I wanted.

Comment: Yes in Bootply (and most fiddle-like sites) you link external resources through another setting, rather than their being directly in the JS or CSS panels.